# Is use of AntiXss library necessary/recommended in mvc 3 razor application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, razor

Is use of AntiXss library necessary/recommended in mvc 3 razor application?  Where can I find out more about encoding options for mvc 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor automatically encodes the output to prevent XSS. If you need to output HTML mark-up then you can use the `@Html.Raw(myVariable)` method or make sure the variables you need to not be encoded are of type `HtmlString`.